# Nest CLI - what is the main.hmr.ts file?

Tags: nestjs

When you create a new application with

```
nest new myApp
```

it creates a main.hmr.ts file.  This file varies from the main.ts in that the bootstrap function contains the code:

```
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => app.close());
  }
```

The declaration for *module* is:

```
declare const module: any;
```

I'm wondering what the intent of this code is...

Answer (score 4):

Ok - it's used by WebPack Hot Module Replacement...

https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/